# Issue with ::after pseudo-elements and data attributes in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm facing an issue with using the ::after pseudo-elements and data attributes in CSS. I'm trying to display custom error messages after my form fields using the data-error and data-error1 attributes, but only data-error seems to be working correctly.

I've checked my JavaScript code, and it seems to be functioning properly. However, the styles for the ::after pseudo-elements for data-error1 are not being applied.

I've used the following code:

HTML:

```
              <div
                class="formData birthdate" data-error="Vous devez entrer votre date de naissance." data-error-visible="false" data-error-1="Vous devez être majeur pour participer à cet événement" data-error-1-visible="false">
                <label for="birthdate">Date de naissance</label><br>
                <input
                  class="text-control"
                  type="date"
                  id="birthdate"
                  name="birthdate"
                /><br>
              </div>
```

CSS :

```
.formData[data-error-1]::after {
  content: attr(data-error-1);
  font-size: 0.4em;
  color: #e54858;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 0.3;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.formData[data-error]::after {
  content: attr(data-error);
  font-size: 0.4em;
  color: #e54858;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 0.3;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.formData[data-error-visible="true"]::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.formData[data-error-1-visible="true"]::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.formData[data-error-visible="true"] .text-control {
  border: 2px solid #e54858;
}
.formData[data-error-1-visible="true"] .text-control {
  border: 2px solid #e54858;
}
```

JS

```
    const birthdateCheck = (value) => {
        const error = document.querySelector('.birthdate');
        let valid = false;
        const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

        if (!value) {
            error.setAttribute('data-error-visible', 'true');
            error.setAttribute('data-error-1-visible', 'false');
        }
        else {
            error.setAttribute('data-error-visible', 'false');
            const parts = value.split('/');
            const birthYear = parseInt(parts[0], 10);

            if (currentYear - birthYear < 18) {
                console.log(error);
                error.setAttribute('data-error-1-visible', 'true');
            } 
            else {
                valid = true;
                error.setAttribute('data-error-1-visible', 'false');
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }
```

I've checked the CSS selectors and the order of CSS files loading, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the source of the issue.

Can you provide any suggestions or advice on how to resolve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Comment: In **CSS**, selector is missing on `line 1`.

Comment: You have issues with the code you have added here, html, css & js is broken, your data tag is actually `data-error-1-visible` but you have `data-error1-visible` in your js

Comment: I'm sorry for the error but the css selector is indeed present in my code '.formData[data-error-1]::after {'  and I had for my the name of my data I just had to modify again after my tests but with the same name it does not work

Comment: I suggest you edit the code in your question so it is correct (data-error1 versus data-error-1).

Comment: I have modified everything as you told me and it is always the first error which is displayed but which cannot be removed, yet it goes false in the tag but not visually? (I made the change in the topic you can watch)

Comment: I noticed that if I place my   ```
.formData[data-error]::after {
  content: attr(data-error);
  font-size: 0.4em;
  color: #e54858;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  text-align: right;
  line height: 0.3;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
```
Before the other it is my second error which is put directly and more the other?

Comment: You can't have two after pseudo elements on one element.

Comment: ok thank you but how can i do

Comment: Set up for just the one pseudo element. The only thing you change is the content depending on which (if any) error has occurred.

Comment: I can't be two different errors if I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes you can have more than one error. Will more than one ever need to be shown at once?

Comment: just one at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element 'has' only one after pseudo element.

What you need to do is change its content to be the relevant error message, or empty if there is no error.

```html
<style>
  .formData.birthdate::after {
    content: '';
    font-size: 0.4em;
    color: #e54858;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 0.3;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
  }
  
  .formData[data-error-visible="true"]::after {
    opacity: 1;
    content: attr(data-error);
  }
  
  .formData[data-error-1-visible="true"]::after {
    opacity: 1;
    content: attr(data-error-1);
  }
  
  .formData[data-error-visible="true"] .text-control {
    border: 2px solid #e54858;
  }
  
  .formData[data-error-1-visible="true"] .text-control {
    border: 2px solid #e54858;
  }
</style>
<div class="formData birthdate" data-error="Vous devez entrer votre date de naissance." data-error-visible="false" data-error-1="Vous devez être majeur pour participer à cet événement" data-error-1-visible="false">
  <label for="birthdate">Date de naissance</label><br>
  <input class="text-control" type="date" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" /><br>
</div>
<script>
  const birthdateCheck = (value) => {
    const error = document.querySelector('.birthdate');
    let valid = false;
    const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

    if (!value) {
      error.setAttribute('data-error-visible', 'true');
      error.setAttribute('data-error-1-visible', 'false');
    } else {
      error.setAttribute('data-error-visible', 'false');
      const parts = value.split('/');
      const birthYear = parseInt(parts[0], 10);

      if (currentYear - birthYear < 18) {
        console.log(error);
        error.setAttribute('data-error-1-visible', 'true');
      } else {
        valid = true;
        error.setAttribute('data-error-1-visible', 'false');
      }
    }
    return valid;
  }
</script>
```